# verb - Is there a word for 'de-acknowledging'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a singular word for the act of 'de-acknowledging' or 'removing an acknowledgement'.

For context:
I am creating a computer program with a list of issues. Issues can be acknowledged. But these acknowledgements can than be removed again.

I would like to put a singular word on the button that performs this action.

Comment: How about renounce : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renounce

Comment: As such, an acknowledgment is not something that can be "removed," "rescinded," "revoked" or negated in any way. We may initially provide a "provisional acknowledgment" that can later be either "confirmed" or "canceled."

Comment: BTW, neither *unacknowledge* nor *disacknowledge* -- and there's no such word as *"de-acknowledge."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a software engineer, I am sure the word you are looking for is **Revoke**

Comment: +1 See also my comment at OP.

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledgements can be *withdrawn*.

> **Withdraw** *verb*
>   4 Discontinue or no longer provide (something previously supplied or offered)
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/withdraw)

Here are some usage examples:

- If you wish to withdraw this Acknowledgement, you must do so within 60 days, ... [- Montana Department of Public Health & Human Services](https://dphhs.mt.gov/Portals/85/csed/documents/ack-withdrawalpaternity.pdf)
- If a further acknowledgement of service is inadvertently filed, an immediate application should be made, supported by evidence, for permission to withdraw it. - [Herbert Smith Freehills](http://hsfnotes.com/litigation/2015/04/09/dangers-of-filing-further-acknowledgement-of-service-when-appealing-jurisdiction-judgment/)

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledge/Ignore or Acknowledge/Revert is what you are looking for...

Acknowledge means accept or admit or recognize

In this context you have to revert back the acknowledgement, so Revert can be used. Ignore can even be used.

Answer (score 0):

Being unclear what you mean by *issue*, I nevertheless have the feeling that what you want here is *recant* - echoing Galileo: *I recant, she revolves*. *Renege* is a possibility, but it carries a taint of reprensibility.